# Solving A System Of ODE's On MAPLE 17

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, vector-analysis, maple

I Have the velocity fields for two vortices that are located at two different points

${\bf{x_1}}(x_1,y_1)$, ${\bf{x_2}}(x_2,y_2)$

$\vec{V_1} = (u_1,v_1) = \frac{\Gamma_1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2}(-(y-y_1),(x-x_1))$
$\vec{V_2} = (u_2,v_2) = \frac{\Gamma_2}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2}(-(y-y_2),(x-x_2))$

I now consider an assumption that vortex one 1 is transported by the velocity of vortex 2. and this leads to a system of ODEs.

$$\frac{dx_1}{dt} = u_2 = \frac{\Gamma_2}{2\pi}\frac{-(y-y_2)}{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2}$$
$$\frac{dy_1}{dt} = v_2 =  \frac{\Gamma_2}{2\pi}\frac{(x-x_2)}{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2} $$
$$\frac{dx_2}{dt} = u_1 = \frac{\Gamma_1}{2\pi}\frac{-(y-y_1)}{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2}$$
$$\frac{dy_2}{dt} = v_1 =  \frac{\Gamma_1}{2\pi}\frac{(x-x_1)}{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2} $$

I now am trying to solve this system of ODEs using maple.

where I consider **x1**=(-1,0) and **x2**=(1,0)

In maple:

```
u(x,y,t) := (-( y))/(2*Pi*((x-1)^(2)+(y)^(2)));
v(x,y,t):=((x-1))/(2*Pi*((x-1)^(2)+(y)^(2)));
f(x,y,t):= ((y))/(2*Pi*((x+1)^(2)+(y)^(2)));
g(x,y,t):=(-(x-1))/(2*Pi*((x-1)^(2)+(y)^(2)))

ODEs := diff(a(t), t) = u(x(t), y(t), t), diff(b(t), t) = v(x(t), y(t), t), diff(c(t), t) = f(x(t), y(t), t), diff(d(t), t) = g(x(t), y(t), t)
```

but am now running into the problem of having 4 equations and 6 unknowns.

4 equations are the ODEs, and 6 unknowns are a,b,c,d, x and y.

I am obviously missing something when i'm writing the system of ODE's down in maple could some one help me with this.

I need to sovle this system and plot it to determine the pathlines.

I know the pathlines should be vertical lines for my current u,v,f,g.